# How are Android's default styles (particularly ButtonBar and ButtonBar.Button) rendered?

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, android-styles

In most examples for ICS+ button bars, namely this one by a Google engineer: https://gist.github.com/2357306

I see a reference to these styles:

```
style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
```

So I opened up Android's attrs.xml, and this is what I see:

```
    <!-- Style for buttons within button bars -->
    <attr name="buttonBarButtonStyle" format="reference" />

    <!-- Style for button bars -->
    <attr name="buttonBarStyle" format="reference" />
```

That's it. So maybe it's a style, right? Here's styles.xml:

```
    <style name="Widget.Holo.ButtonBar">
        <item name="android:divider">?android:attr/dividerVertical</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Holo.ButtonBar.Button">
    </style>
```

Huh? And yet Eclipse and devices are able to render them like this:

[image: Button bar on ICS]

So how is it getting the right dimensions and stuff? The reason I need them is that I want to use this style of button bar on Gingerbread and below, which lack the `buttonBarStyle` attribute. Thus, they render wrong:

[image: Button bar on GB]

Answer (score 1):

This is because of style inheritance. Widget.Holo.ButtonBar inherits all styles of "Widget.Holo" and "Widget" as well.